# XmlDocument SelectSingleNode of improperly formed XML

Tags: c#, xmldocument, selectsinglenode

I have a `XmlDocument` which is not properly formed

```
<library>
  <dept>
    <books></books>
    <language></language>
  </dept>
  <dept>
    <lecturer></lecturer>
  </dept>
</library>
```

I want to do a `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode` for 'lecturer' tag.

When I select ChildNodes of `<library>` tag, I get only `<books>` and `<language>` but not `<lecturer>`. 
How do I get XmlNode object of  tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML is well formed XML. It would not load into a `XmlDocument` otherwise.

The only `ChildNodes` of `library` are `dept` nodes.

To get lecturer, you can do the following:

```
XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("library/dept/lecturer");
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I missed one more tag in there. <location>. 
How do I get to lecturer tag now?

<library> 
  <dept> 
    <books></books> 
    <language></language> 
  </dept> 
  <location></location>
  <dept> 
    <lecturer></lecturer> 
  </dept> 
</library>

Thank you
Sid

Comment: @user315445 (Sid) - it doesn't change, as the `location` tag is in the same _level_ as `dept`.

Comment: Actually I had to parse a csproj file but I had problems in getting the PostBuildEvent tag. So, instead of using selectSingleNode, I used GetElementsByTagName(). And it solved my problem.
Thanks for the answer Jeff else I would have spent more time on SelectSingleNode method.

Answer (score 0):

To parse csproj file, use GetElementsByTagName(). I dont know why SelectSingleNode() is not working!

Thank you
Sid

Comment: If this is a new question, you should add it as a new question. For info, with csproj the issue is usually that it is namespaced xml, which is... trickier.